# downgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to downgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2008. I am using Window Server 2008. Any reference documents?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Gold badge, silver badges, 119 questions... . And still not learned how to ask questions. What is your question here? If there are documents? Yes, there are documents. But not one that describes any downgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. It was never possible with any version to do a downgrade.

And this question is a duplicate of a still answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849496/downgrade-sql-server-2008-r2-to-sql-server-2008

Comment: Thanks mailq. I mean downgrade the SQL Server 2008 R2 software itself, not the data file. I think the document is talking about downgrade the data file? Any comments for my requirements?

Comment: Downgrade the software is easy: Uninstall the new one and afterwards install the old one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to downgrade an instance.  You can uninstall the database instance and install an older version, but you can not take the newer SQL Server 2008 R2 database (or its backup) and attach it to the older SQL Server 2008 instance.  This has never been supported.

Comment: Thanks mrdenny. I mean downgrade the SQL Server 2008 R2 software itself, not the data file. I think you are talking about downgrade the data file? Any comments for my requirements?

Comment: There isno way to downgrade the software. You will need to do a full uninstall and install of the older version.